# while adding tab, i am getting this exception, how can i solve this?

Tags: gwt, extjs

```
public void addTab(String text, Widget widget) {
    TabItem item = new TabItem();
    item.setText(text);
    item.setClosable(true);
//item.add((Widget) new Dashboard());
    tabPanel.add(item);
    tabPanel.setSelection(item);
}
```

While Executing  i am getting this exception,
how can i solve this problem in gxt. i am trying to add tab, but it gives this exception

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: null
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.Component.fireEvent(Component.java:293)
    at com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.button.IconButton.onClick(IconButton.java:215)
    at com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.button.IconButton.onBrowserEvent(IconButton.java:196)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
```

Comment: Is the tabPanel null?

Comment: Is the stacktrace complete?

Comment: can you provide more code and the full stacktrace?

Comment: i got the solution. i forgot to set tab panel in my class..